# How to assign a size to a new string? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to create an array of pointers to strings. I want each of the strings to have only 3 chars. This is the code I have so far:

```
 string **ptr=new string *[100];    // An array of 100 pointers to strings

for (i=0;i<100; i++)            // Assigning each pointer with a new string
{
    ptr[i]=new string;
    (*ptr[i])[3];
}
```

I am having trouble with the line (*ptr[i])[3]). If I were to create a srting with only 3 chars not via a pointer I would write:

```
string str[3];
```

How do I assign 3 chars with the pointer? Thanks!

Comment: `string str(3, ' ');`

Comment: `string str[3]` doesn't create a string with 3 characters, it creates an array of 3 strings.

Comment: Why do you want an array of pointers to strings? Use an array of strings (or a vector, if the size isn't fixed) and save yourself a whole pile of memory-management headaches.

Comment: _"I am having trouble with the line (*ptr[i])[3]"_ Don't write code that looks like that then!  Patient: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Don't do that then."

Comment: I got confused with the str[3]. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

```
std::vector<std::string> vec(100, "   ");
```

That does exactly what you are looking for without the need to manage memory yourself.

```
string str[3];
```

That does not create a string with 3 characters, but an array of 3 strings.

Comment: well, except that's not an array of string pointers, it's an array of strings (granted, he probably wants this, not pointers)

Comment: @Dave Agreed, it doesn't do *exactly* what he is trying to do ... it does it **better** ;)

Answer (score -1):

`(*ptr[i])[3];` simply accesses the fourth character in the string, it doesn't resize it.  The std::string DOES provide a `resize()` method though.

As already mentioned, `string str[3]` creates an array of three strings but I don't think you're trying to talk about that.

As already pointed out, you can use the string ctor that takes a size argument and a fill char, like so:

```
ptr[i]=new string( 3, ' ' );
```

And of course you should use vector.

Comment: Excuse me, what? That's not *at all* what happens in that line. It creates an array of 3 default initialized instances of `std::string`. If you invoke `operator[]` on an actual object, you're right (and if the index is actually >= 0 and < `string::size()`).

Comment: Sorry, that's completely incorrect.  This is a declaration for an array of 3 strings.

Comment: @thokra I think he meant the `(*ptr[i])[3];` line, which does attempt to access the **4th** element of the string (not the 3rd).

Comment: @JohnDibling @thokra It's a typo, in fact. I didn't mean to include `string`.  I just brain farted all over the interwebs and it has cost me dearly... :#)

Comment: Another thing, why the `resize()` suggestion? Do you want to resize an empty `string` to a `string` of `size() == 3`?

Comment: Has he edited the question?  Cos it don't read now like wot I thought it read when.  I'm sure he explicitly mentioned resizing...

Comment: Well, in an effort not to leave wrong answers out there I've sorted it.  Or, if everyone's agreed, we could delete the internet and start again...?